# How to retrieve the keywords of ASIN from Amazon by code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

How to retrieve the keywords of ASIN from Amazon by code ?

I tried to scrape the amazon pages and find the keyword tag but not correct values it is.

Amazon product keywords are under seller central.
There are any ways to get the keywords of ASIN from code ?

Comment: Have you managed to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to retrieve the keywords of ASIN from Amazon **by code** ?

Do you mean html source code?

I've been working for a while on this kind of web scraping. There is no easy way because there are many templates/variations/tags in most product pages.

URL pattern is the best/easy way IMO

> www.amazon.XXX/OPTIONAL_DESC/dp/ASIN

Any way, Amazon have one of the best [API & SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) in order to do this work in your favourite languaje (Phyton, Java, PHP)

Comment: Hi John

Thanks for you your replay.
My issue is how to get the keywords of an ASIN.

URL pattern like www.amazon.com/OPTIONAL_DESC/dp/B00NAWQHNE  or https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00NAWQHNE is not returns the keywords of ASIN.
I want reverse engineering to get keywords.

Which Amazon MWS API returns the keywprds of ASIN ?
or from Amazon web pages source, how to get keywords?

Comment: Sorry about my misunderstanding, did you try using this html tag/name:<meta name="keywords" content="product meta keywords" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
jQuery("#ASIN").val();
```